# How to convert dataframe rows to IndexedRow in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I have a table which looks like this:

```
+-------+---- -+-------+-------+----
|movieId|Action| Comedy|Fantasy| ...
+-------+----- +-------+-------+----
|  1001 |  1   |   1   |   0   | ...
|  1011 |  0   |   1   |   1   | ...
+-------+------+-------+-------+----
```

How to convert its each row to IndexedRow? so I have something like this:

```
+-------+----------------+
|movieId|    Features    |
+-------+----------------+
|  1001 | [1, 1, 0, ...] | 
|  1011 | [0, 1, 1, ...] |
+-------+----------------+
```

Comment: Use [`VectorAssembler`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler)

Answer (score 0):

If you need the array type output, you can use the array() function.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
tst= spark.createDataFrame([(1,7,80),(1,8,40),(1,5,100),(5,8,90),(7,6,50),(0,3,60)],schema=['col1','col2','col3'])
tst_arr= tst.withColumn("Features",F.array(tst.columns))

tst_arr.show()
+----+----+----+-----------+
|col1|col2|col3|   Features|
+----+----+----+-----------+
|   1|   7|  80| [1, 7, 80]|
|   1|   8|  40| [1, 8, 40]|
|   1|   5| 100|[1, 5, 100]|
|   5|   8|  90| [5, 8, 90]|
|   7|   6|  50| [7, 6, 50]|
|   0|   3|  60| [0, 3, 60]|
+----+----+----+-----------+
```

If you are trying to do this for ML operations then better to use a vector assembler : http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/_modules/pyspark/ml/feature.html#VectorAssembler